# VAADIN: Size of UI.access() push queue

Tags: user-interface, queue, vaadin

I would like to monitor my pushs' to the clients with the famous 
UI.access() ... sequence  on the server side.

Background is that I have to propagate lots of pushs to my client and I 
want to make sure, nothing gets queued up.

I found only client RPCQueue having a size(), but I have no idea if its the correct items searching for now how to access this.

Thanks for any hint.

Gerry

Comment: I would use network tab of Chrome dev tools, probably temporarily using long polling mode for push for testing.

Comment: It is good to be concerned about this if you have lot of push activity. General rule of thumb is not to lock UI for long time, i.e. keep push operations as atomic as possible.

Comment: Thanks,
but I want to look from inside my (server) code to the queue/s. 

As I do  not use Chrome, its not an option.

"... as atomic as possible" , means as short as possible, but what is the measure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the size of the queue of tasks that have been enqueued using `UI.access` but not yet run, then you can use `VaadinSession.getPendingAccessQueue`.

This will, however, not give the full picture since it doesn't cover changes that have been applied to the server-side state (i.e. the `UI.access` task has already been executed) but not yet sent to the client. Those types of changes are tracked in a couple of different places depending on the type of change and the Vaadin version you're using.

For this kind of use case, it might be good to use the built-in `beforeClientResponse` functionality to apply your own changes as late as possible instead of applying changes eagerly.

With Vaadin versions up to 8, you do this by overriding the `beforeClientResponse` method in your component or extension class. You need to use `markAsDirty()` to ensure that `beforeClientResponse` will eventually be run for that instance.

Wit Vaadin 10 and newer, there's instead a `UI.beforeClientResponse` to which you give a callback that will be run once at an appropriate time by the framework.

Comment: Thank your very much for this detailed and expressive answer ! 
Gerry